# Does deleting an Office 365 user also delete their SharePoint Online files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-accounts

I've been having difficulty finding an answer to this question.

When I delete an Office 365 user account (and their license), it warns me that their data will be deleted as well.  Does this include documents & files that they've created in SharePoint Online Sites, or will they be kept?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Removing a user will not remove their files they created on SharePoint sites that are not their OneDrive. Eventually, after 30 days, their person site , which contains their OneDrive, will be purged. In addition to the article mentioned earlier, see also this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2619308

Answer (score 2):

Apparently they are purged after 30 days. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/3042522 for some background and useful information.

Cheers

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm talking about files they've put on to Team Sites, where the Site itself wasn't created by them.  Not their own "personal" site.  I had a read through that page, but it doesn't seem to say anything about this.

Comment: OIC, I thought you meant their personal one-drive for business site. Sorry nothing but guesses and assumptions about the latter. Would find it very hard to believe that files in team sites would be purged!